# pivot all the columns of a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot, bar-chart

I have this dataframe:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'Jan' : ['US', 'GB', 'NL', 'CH', 'GB', 'US'],
                  'Feb': ['US', 'AU', 'RU', 'NO', 'AU', 0],
                  'Mar' : ['PL', 'AU', 'FI', 'US', 'CH', 'CH']})
```

I would like to create stacked barchart to show the count of countries per month. So I need first to transform this dataframe to this form :

```
      Jan  Feb  Mar
  US   2    1    1
  GB   2    0    0
  NL   1    0    0
  CH   1    0    2
  AU   0    2    1
  RU   0    1    0 
  NO   0    1    0
  PL   0    0    1
  FI   0    0    1
  0    0    1    0
```

My dataframe is large but I want to display the most 10 common countries for each month on the stacked barplot. I noticed that pandas pivot isn't doing the Job.

Comment: Thank you for the remark. I made the modification

Answer (score 2):

You could

```
In [46]: s = df.stack().reset_index()

In [47]: pd.crosstab(s[0], s['level_1']).rename_axis(None, 1).rename_axis(None, 0)
Out[47]:
    Feb  Jan  Mar
0     1    0    0
AU    2    0    1
CH    0    1    2
FI    0    0    1
GB    0    2    0
NL    0    1    0
NO    1    0    0
PL    0    0    1
RU    1    0    0
US    1    2    1
```

Comment: This answers exactly my question.